# v-show not working when I submit the form without choosing any data

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Html template

```
<div class="control-group">
                <label for="MainContent_ddlCourse" id="MainContent_Label1" class="control-label">Course</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <select name="ctl00$MainContent$ddlCourse" id="MainContent_ddlCourse" class="input-block-level" v-model="selectedCourse" v-on:change="courseChanged">
                        <option value="">Please choose...</option>
                        <option v-for="course in courseList" v-bind:value="course.CourseId">{{ course.Name }}</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <p v-if="invalidCourse">Invalid Course Selected</p>
            </div>
```

THis is my JS

```
   if (!this.selectedCourse) invalidCourse = true;
```

Comment: use v-if instead of v-show might solve the problem

Comment: where is `v-show` in your code ?

Comment: if you talking about `v-if` then change in subject title

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are talking about `v-if` not `v-show`, you need to add `this` to use vue data

```
    if (!this.selectedCourse) this.invalidCourse = true;
```

or simply reverse the condition

```
    <p v-if="!selectedCourse">Invalid Course Selected</p>
```